# Find the set of points of discontinuity of the given function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $$ D =\{ {\frac{1}{n}}\ | n \in \mathbb N \}  \cup \{0\} $$and $f : D \rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by  $f(\frac{1}{n}) = n$ and $f(0) = 1 $. I need to find the set of points of discontinuity of $f$.

---

I think the function is continuous over **D**. So set of discontinuities is the empty set, ie. **∅**

Comment: The only accumulation point of $D$ is $0$, thus it is the only candidate for a discontinuity point. Try to verify whether for every sequence of points from $D$ converging to $0$, denoted by $x_n$, you have that $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(0)$.

Comment: Okay I understand
Xn=1/n on D . Xn-->0
But, f(Xn)--/--> f(0)
Violets Sequential criteria for continuity
So discontinuous at 0

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): edit your post to include some attempts, even if they failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We say $f$ is discontinuity at a point $p$:
$$\exists \epsilon>0, \forall \delta>0, |f(x)-f(p)|\geq\epsilon$$ $\exists x_0 \in D $, for which $|x-p|<\delta.$
$0$ is a limit point of $D$, let's check whether $f$ is discontinuity at point $0$. 
let $\epsilon=1$:
if $\delta\geq \frac{1}{2}$, set $x_0=\frac{1}{2}$, then $|f(\frac{1}{2})-1| = |2-1|\geq 1$
if $0<\delta<\frac{1}{2}$, set $x_0 = \frac{1}{[\frac{1}{\delta}]}$, then $|f(\frac{1}{[\frac{1}{\delta}]})-1|=|[\frac{1}{\delta}]-1|>1$ 
so $f$ is discontinuity as $0$.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This question goes against [our quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.